# Read class from KProperty1 in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Is it possible to read out the class type K of a KProperty1<K, V> in Kotlin?

```
val kProperty1: KProperty1<User, Long> = User::id
```

How to get the class type User of kProperty?

Comment: Probably not due to type erasure: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/generics.html#type-erasure

Comment: I think the real question here is what are you actually trying to accomplish? This smells potentially like a case of the XY problem https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem